# Почему не открывается активити?

Tags: android, java

Столкнулся с проблемой открытия активити. Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на ссылке в WebView открывалось новой активити. Я делаю так

```
                      ...................

arhivView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());  
                       ..................
```

где класс myWebViewClient

```
  public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {

        @Override//тут отлавливается нажатие на ссылку
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            trunsitionTo tr = new trunsitionTo();            
            tr.startMaps(convertStringToByte(getStringArr(url)));
            return true;
        }
...

    }
```

и класс trunsitionTo(он всего с одним методом, был написан в связи  с отсутствием множественного наследования в Java)

```
public class trunsitionTo  extends Activity
{

    public void startMaps(byte[] info)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,NavigatingActivity.class);//на этой строке все вылетает

        intent.putExtra("allBalloon",false);
        intent.putExtra("infoBuilding",info);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

но приложение не работает. Уже и не знаю, что делать.

**Лог:**

```
04-01 13:09:26.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(915): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:2551)
        at Vesna.Upi.UseIT.trunsitionTo.startMaps(trunsitionTo.java:25)
        at Vesna.Upi.UseIT.myWebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(myWebViewClient.java:20)
        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:193)
        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:304)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Вопрос решен!**
Сейчас это выглядит так,

```
public class NewsActivity extends Activity 
{

    private  WebView arhivView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.news_page);
         arhivView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient(this));
         ...
         ...
         ...
    }

  ...
  ...
  ...

   //этот класс располагается внутри класса  NewsActivity, чтобы было наследование от Activity   
   private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        Context mContext;
        myWebViewClient(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {

            byte[] m = convertStringToByte(getStringArr(url));
            startMaps(convertStringToByte(getStringArr(url)));
            return true;
        }

        public void startMaps(byte[] info)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NavigatingActivity.class);
            //intent.setClass(this,NavigatingActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("allBalloon",false);
            intent.putExtra("infoBuilding",info);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что то как то некрасиво выглядит код. Во первых, соблюдайте конвенцию имен, во вторых, касаемо вашей проблемы, все активити должны открываться через интент а не так:

> trunsitionTo tr = new trunsitionTo();

тогда у вас контекст проинициализируется, я бы предложил в классе trunsitionTo держать контекст, а не наследовать класс от Activity

Comment: Если бы я мог открыть через интент в первом классе, я бы это сделал. Как вы могли заметить, то первый класс наследуется от WebViewClient, а значит не может уже наследоваться от Activity => метод startActivity(intent) не может быть вызван напрямую, поэтому то и пришлось извратиться. Если вы можете предложить другой способ открытия нового активити при нажатие на ссылку в WebView, то я буду только рад :)

Comment: public class trunsitionTo
{
    private Context mContext;
    public trunsitionTo(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
    }


    public void startMaps(byte[] info)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NavigatingActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("allBalloon",false);
        intent.putExtra("infoBuilding",info);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

Comment: пробрасывайте контекст из исходной активити

Comment: Что-то не видно что вы так делали. А вот нашел свой косяк, mContext.startActivity(intent) должен быть

Comment: так, я попробовал так, у меня не вышло, вот я и убрал это.
сейчас написал как вы предложили.
   

   

      public void startMaps(byte[] info)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,NavigatingActivity.class);
                //intent.setClass(this,NavigatingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("allBalloon",false);
                intent.putExtra("infoBuilding",info);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            
    
    }


но ничего не выло, ошибка такая же

Comment: конструктор trunsitionTo покажите и его создание в myWebViewClient

Comment: NavigatingActivity покажи этот класс еще

Comment: я добавил в описание вопроса, как это сейчас выглядит

Answer (score 0):

```
public class trunsitionTo  extends Activity
```

где переопределенный метод онКриейт?

Comment: так а что должно измениться?
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
добавил я его, но все по прежнему вылетает

Comment: выложи лог ошибки =)

Comment: ок, я добавил